# Postgres SQL always returns error string

Tags: server, postgresql

I have been having alot of postgresSQL issues mostly due to me not really understanding how it works very well, if at all. Whenever I try anything interacting with PostgresSQL i get this return

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I check SystemCTL and this is what is returned [image: s status postgresql, active (exited) since 1 week and 4 days ago.]

I am planning on using postgresql for forgejo, a self hosted git server and akkoma. I have checked the make sure the port is open. I have not modified any files within postgresql

some one suggest i add the output of `sudo ls -la /var/run/postgresql`
[image]

Comment: Please add to your original post the output of: sudo ls -la /var/run/postgresql   That will show which port exists.  Sometimes a postgresql install will grab the next port (5433) if there is already a running postgresql on 5432 -- so you can run in parallel until you are satisfied with the new release.

Comment: @ubfan1 added it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the postgresql 15 got installed with an existing postgresql 14, so to keep things running on the existing db, the install procedure gave the postgresql 15 the next port, 5433.
This is simply a configuration line in /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf (around line 64).  You can simply edit in the change and restart posgresql, but ensure your postgresql 14 (assumed to be capable of running on port 5432)  has been fully migrated, and can be removed.